# Looking for an addon to automatically select all instances of selected word in the current page

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, firefox-addon, mozilla

I am looking for an addon to install so that when you select a word in a webpage ( by clicking) it automatically highlights all the instances of that selected words in that text. There used to be this 
[highlightall](https://addons.mozilla.org/eN-US/firefox/addon/highlightall/) addon but it no longer works for recent version of Firefox! It was ver handy as all you had to do is to select that word and all instances get highlighted

Such an addon would be very helpful when reading a code as you can simply select a variable name and it would select everywhere that variable has been used in the code so you could understand the program better.

Comment: ok i man in understand what you want. think of a good name for the addon, also are you willing to write some design notes on the wiki page. ill make a repo and you can write about it like how to use it and how you want this addon to be.

Comment: @Noitidart dude for just 50 bounty you'll make this guy an addon? Desperate? ...

Comment: I think it's a decent idea and am willing to make it, i think i can learn a lot from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok man I made the addon and released it at AMO. I called [HiliteOnSelection](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hiliteonselection/) I linkified it.

Use it tell me how it works tell me how you would like to change it etc. I appreciate feedback.

More than 50 bounty would have been nice too, a side effect was I learned a lot so it's cool.

Comment: There's room for improvment, if you want to help me by giving some design notes let me know, theres a public wiki you can edit on https://github.com/Noitidart/HiliteOnSelection/wiki

Comment: Thank you for asking for inputs. At this moment I only have one suggestion. The name you picked for your add on is not very descriptive and users might not be able to find it and I believe the number one priority is to get more users. Why not to pick something like "HighlightAllWords" or "HighlightAllOccurrences" or "HighlightandSelectAll" and also to provide more detailed descriptions with the use of more keywords like Highlight, occurances, select all, "useful for reading programming codes", "Highlight all variables in code" etc. Your work is perfect,  just needs marketing.

Comment: Thanks man I'm also not a fan of the name. I like those but was hoping for an even more creative name. Can you write the detailed descriptions and other stuff I'll go with that, I'm busy with some other addons right now, so if you can knock out the writing and naming that would be awesome

Comment: Sure I will do my best, give me some time please

Answer (score 0):

If you press ctrl+f and then click highlight all it will do it.

If you want to copy it heres the code for highlihgt all:

```
function toggleHighlight(aHighlight) {

          if (!this._dispatchFindEvent("highlightallchange"))
            return;

          let word = this._findField.value;
          // Bug 429723. Don't attempt to highlight ""
          if (aHighlight && !word)
            return;

          this.browser._lastSearchHighlight = aHighlight;
          this.browser.finder.highlight(aHighlight, word);

}
```

[here it is on mxr](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/content/widgets/findbar.xml#441)

if you need more help let me know

Comment: I dont know what to do with this code? also I knew about the ctrl+f + pressing highlihgt all, if you read my post( or visited the link to the addon) I dont wanna do it that way.

Comment: can you explain to me how this is different than the findbar? the only thing the findbar doenst do is count instances of it

Comment: I am talking about user experience in terms of number of clicks and punches!

Comment: @honestann - calling honestann, you created a [TOPIC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167458/how-does-javascript-execution-context-work-in-firefox-extensions-with-multiple-w) and your addon i noticed does highlighting of text, help a brother out share your code with

Answer (score 0):

Well, my code is quite complex because it performs several advanced services, but if you're asking how to highlight a word of text, the easiest way is to add a style attribute around the word.  For example:

This hot dog needs more mustard.

... would become...

This hot `<span style="color:#FFFF60">dog</span>` needs more mustard.

The above would highlight "dog" in the sentence.  The above assumes white text on black background, where yellow is a good highlight color.  If the text is black on white background, that `#FFFF60` should probably be something like `#40FFC0` or `#40FF40` or `#4040FF` or whatever you find looks good.

When you want to remove the highlight, you can delete the `<span>` element.  In my case I usually put the `style="color:#FFFF60"` in some other existing element, so I don't delete the element to remove the highlight, I delete the `style` attribute I added to the element.

By the way, the reason I change text color to highlight terms is because that does not change the size of the word, and therefore the text never reflows (and screws up formatting).  You could probably change background color to highlight, but I never tried that.

To find all instances of a certain word, I don't know, but probably the TreeWalker is part of the solution.

Comment: Oh yikes! Thats pretty messy. You should also try the toggleHighlight appraoch below, nice share though.

Comment: See my updated solution below you might be interested as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok C Graphics man here's the code

Ok its real easy you don't even have to write another function. Here's the code to highlight any word in the current tab.

```
gBrowser.selectedTab.linkedBrowser.finder.highlight(true, 'YOUR_WORD_HERE')
```

if you want to unighlight then set the first argument to false.

You can do this in any tab just have to supply the browser element within the tab.

like this code here will highlight everything in the first tab:

```
gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[0].linkedBrowser.finder.highlight(true, 'YOUR_WORD_HERE');
```

Comment: @CGraphics i noticed you added a bounty, what exactly are you looking for to give this bounty? would you like a compiled addon?