# Is it possible to highlight all words on a web page without destroying the layout?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom, firefox-addon

I've written an extension for firefox which highlights all words on a web page (excluding some words in a given list).

What i've noticed is that (besides that my extension is terribly slow) some web pages get "destroyed", more specifically the layout gets destroyed (particularly websites with overlay advertising or fancy drop-down menus).

My code wraps `<span>` tags around every "word", or to be precise around every token, because i'm splitting the text nodes with a whitespace as seperator.

So is it possible anyway to realize this task without destroying the page's layout?

I'm iterating over all text nodes, split them, and iterate over every token.
When the token is in my list, i don't highlight it, else i wrap the `<span>` tag around it.

So any suggestions how this could be done faster would be helpful, too.

Here are some screenshots for a correctly highlighted and a not correctly highlighted web page:

right:
[en.wikipedia.org before highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrYJP.jpg), 
[en.wikipedia.org after highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85jTZ.jpg).

wrong:
[developer.mozilla.org before highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THMvV.jpg), 
[developer.mozilla.org after highlighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrcKl.jpg).

Comment: You must be introducing invalid syntax or layouts shouldn't be affected. Do you have a demo?

Comment: Unless your <span> is adding borders, margins and/or padding then the layout shouldn't be affected. You should only be setting the background-color and color properties.

Comment: well i thought so too, but here are some screenshots of a working example: [en.wikipedia.org before](http://imgur.com/FyFunmo.jpg), [en.wikipedia.org after](http://imgur.com/snw0K6v.jpg) and here are some screenshots of a destroyed layout: [developer.mozilla.org before](http://imgur.com/glnLa4U.jpg), [developer.mozilla.org after](http://imgur.com/gn9mOk0.jpg).

Comment: You should no way add spans to highlight a word. See my response here ignore the one that add's spans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156879/looking-for-an-addon-to-automatically-select-all-instances-of-selected-word-in-t/22163697

Comment: @Noitidart: i've tried to call this.browser.finder.highlight(aHighlight, word); but it returns 'this.browser is not defined', so how do i call it?

Comment: I updated the answer with another one so you guys can see how its done, just copy paste. See link in solution below.

Answer (score 2):

OK. Study this code. It searches for all instances of "is" and highlights if it is not surrounded by word characters. Put this in your scratchpad while this tab is focused. You will see that words like "List" and other words containing "Is" are no highlighted, but all the "Is"'s are.

I basically made an addon here for you. You can now release this as an addon called RegEx FindBar and take all the credit....

```
var doc = gBrowser.contentDocument;
var ctrler = _getSelectionController(doc.defaultView);

var searchRange = doc.createRange();
searchRange.selectNodeContents(doc.documentElement);

let startPt = searchRange.cloneRange();
startPt.collapse(true);

let endPt = searchRange.cloneRange();
endPt.collapse(false);

let retRane = null;


let finder = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/rangefind;1"].createInstance().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFind);
finder.caseSensitive = false;
var i = 0;
while (retRange = finder.Find('is', searchRange, startPt, endPt)) {
    i++;
    var stCont = retRange.startContainer;
    var endCont = retRange.endContainer;

    console.log('retRange(' + i + ') = ', retRange);
    console.log('var txt = retRange.commonAncestorContainer.data',retRange.commonAncestorContainer.data);

    //now test if one posiion before startOffset and one position after endOffset are WORD characters

    var isOneCharBeforeStCharWordChar; //var that holds if the character before the start character is a word character
    if (retRange.startOffset == 0) {
        //no characters befor this characte so obviously not a word char
        isOneCharBeforeStCharWordChar = false;
    } else {
        var oneCharBeforeStChar = stCont.data.substr(retRange.startOffset-1,1);
        if (/\w/.test(oneCharBeforeStChar)) {
            isOneCharBeforeStCharWordChar = true;
        } else {
            isOneCharBeforeStCharWordChar = false;
        }
        console.log('oneCharBeforeStChar',oneCharBeforeStChar);
    }

    var isOneCharAfterEndCharWordChar; //var that holds if the character before the start character is a word character
    if (retRange.endOffset == endCont.length - 1) {
        //no characters after this characte so obviously not a word char
        isOneCharAfterEndCharWordChar = false;
    } else {
        var oneCharAferEndChar = endCont.data.substr(retRange.endOffset,1); //no need to subtract 1 from endOffset, it takes into account substr 2nd arg is length and is treated like length I THINK
        if (/\w/.test(oneCharAferEndChar)) {
            isOneCharAfterEndCharWordChar = true;
        } else {
            isOneCharAfterEndCharWordChar = false;
        }
        console.log('oneCharAferEndChar',oneCharAferEndChar);
    }

    if (isOneCharBeforeStCharWordChar == false && isOneCharAfterEndCharWordChar == false) {
        //highlight it as surrounding characters are no word characters
        _highlightRange(retRange, ctrler);
        console.log('highlighted it as it was not surrounded by word charactes');
    } else {
        console.log('NOT hilte it as it was not surrounded by word charactes');
    }


    //break;
    startPt = retRange.cloneRange();
    startPt.collapse(false);
}

/*********************/

function _getEditableNode(aNode) {
    while (aNode) {
      if (aNode instanceof Ci.nsIDOMNSEditableElement)
        return aNode.editor ? aNode : null;

      aNode = aNode.parentNode;
    }
    return null;
  }

function _highlightRange(aRange, aController) {
    let node = aRange.startContainer;
    let controller = aController;

    let editableNode = this._getEditableNode(node);
    if (editableNode)
      controller = editableNode.editor.selectionController;

    let findSelection = controller.getSelection(Ci.nsISelectionController.SELECTION_FIND);
    findSelection.addRange(aRange);

    if (editableNode) {
      // Highlighting added, so cache this editor, and hook up listeners
      // to ensure we deal properly with edits within the highlighting
      if (!this._editors) {
        this._editors = [];
        this._stateListeners = [];
      }

      let existingIndex = this._editors.indexOf(editableNode.editor);
      if (existingIndex == -1) {
        let x = this._editors.length;
        this._editors[x] = editableNode.editor;
        this._stateListeners[x] = this._createStateListener();
        this._editors[x].addEditActionListener(this);
        this._editors[x].addDocumentStateListener(this._stateListeners[x]);
      }
    }
  }

  function _getSelectionController(aWindow) {
    // display: none iframes don't have a selection controller, see bug 493658
    if (!aWindow.innerWidth || !aWindow.innerHeight)
      return null;

    // Yuck. See bug 138068.
    let docShell = aWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                          .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
                          .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShell);

    let controller = docShell.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                             .getInterface(Ci.nsISelectionDisplay)
                             .QueryInterface(Ci.nsISelectionController);
    return controller;
  }
```

Comment: I don't want to release it, i want to learn. Maybe i was overwhelmed of the given feedback, because i've just started with this problem a few days ago and JS is not my field yet. Only problem with the given solution is that the highlighting is gone if "Highlight all" is disabled in the find bar, which is ok to me because i don't want to change the behaviour of the find bar itself.

Comment: Let's use some thought, we can find a way to make it work in parallel with findbar highlight all, but if you do that then definitely change the highlight color of your addon.

Comment: Fantastic solution bro. However I copied and pasted this from MXR so the `createStateListener` and `_editor` stuff is not working right, I actually don't understand that or the `nsISelectionController` stuff. So this code definitely has room for improvement.

Comment: this is based on code shared by me, its not my code, but if you don't mind could I release an addon for "Match Word" functionality, i think ppl will find it very useful

Comment: Sure go ahead. I didn't really give the listerns much thought.

Comment: Oh btw I should probably tell you need to support that. What it does is the controller within text editable elements (aka editors) have their own selection. the nsIFinder will get ranges in there, so you will need to removeRanges from the controllers within the editors. You may want to use the listeners, as when a user edits the field you will likely want to remove the highlight.

Answer (score 1):

Oh edit my solution out, will update with proper solution, I see you want to highlight all words

This is the code how firefox highlights stuff without changing document: [Finder.jsm - _highlight function](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/modules/Finder.jsm#225). You will have to copy this and use it for the whole document, if you need help let me know and I'll do it.

Here was my solution to highlight all matches of single word: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22206366/1828637

Here man this is how you are going to highlight the whole document, I didn't finish the snippet but this is the start of it: [Gist - HighlightTextInDocument](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9374173)

Comment: I think it's easier to iterate over all text nodes and use 'gFindBar._highlightDoc(true, word)' on every token generated by splitting .textContent of the text node.

Comment: I've noticed now that this way can't work, for example if there is the word 'apple' on my list (so it's blacklisted for highlighting), words like 'a' will cause partially highlighting of the word 'apple'. Next problem is that you have to sort the list of words on the page to highlight them correctly, else firefox is going to avoid highlighting because of overlapping.

Comment: Ah that is definitely a problem. The issue lies in the `Ci.nsISelectionController.SELECTION_FIND` if you change that to `2` it will be like normal selection. to find out the codes you can set it to see here [MXR - SourceCode of nsISelectionController](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/content/base/public/nsISelectionController.idl#30)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the copy paste answer to highlight everything in the document. As you learn more about it share with us, like how you can highlight with a different color, right now its all pink O_O

```
  function _getEditableNode(aNode) {
    while (aNode) {
      if (aNode instanceof Ci.nsIDOMNSEditableElement)
        return aNode.editor ? aNode : null;

      aNode = aNode.parentNode;
    }
    return null;
  }

function _highlightRange(aRange, aController) {
    let node = aRange.startContainer;
    let controller = aController;

    let editableNode = this._getEditableNode(node);
    if (editableNode)
      controller = editableNode.editor.selectionController;

    let findSelection = controller.getSelection(Ci.nsISelectionController.SELECTION_FIND);
    findSelection.addRange(aRange);

    if (editableNode) {
      // Highlighting added, so cache this editor, and hook up listeners
      // to ensure we deal properly with edits within the highlighting
      if (!this._editors) {
        this._editors = [];
        this._stateListeners = [];
      }

      let existingIndex = this._editors.indexOf(editableNode.editor);
      if (existingIndex == -1) {
        let x = this._editors.length;
        this._editors[x] = editableNode.editor;
        this._stateListeners[x] = this._createStateListener();
        this._editors[x].addEditActionListener(this);
        this._editors[x].addDocumentStateListener(this._stateListeners[x]);
      }
    }
  }

  function _getSelectionController(aWindow) {
    // display: none iframes don't have a selection controller, see bug 493658
    if (!aWindow.innerWidth || !aWindow.innerHeight)
      return null;

    // Yuck. See bug 138068.
    let docShell = aWindow.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                          .getInterface(Ci.nsIWebNavigation)
                          .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDocShell);

    let controller = docShell.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                             .getInterface(Ci.nsISelectionDisplay)
                             .QueryInterface(Ci.nsISelectionController);
    return controller;
  }
var doc = gBrowser.contentDocument;
var searchRange = doc.createRange();
searchRange.selectNodeContents(doc.documentElement);
_highlightRange(searchRange,_getSelectionController(gBrowser.contentWindow))
```

Comment: I did it with 'gFindBar._highlightDoc(true, word)' now. I'm using firefox 17, so i dont know if gFindBar is state of the art.

Answer (score 1):

@jervis, I can't make a comment on your comment under @Noitidart code as I don't have 50rep yet. So I have to post here.

Re:

> I did it with 'gFindBar._highlightDoc(true, word)' now. I'm using firefox 17, so i dont know if gFindBar is state of the art. –  jervis 40 mins ago

But I tested his code and and it works.

Don't use gFindBar.

Copy it and then paste it into your Scratchpad.

Why are you using `gFindBar._highlightDoc(true, word)` ? I thoght you wanted to highlight everything in the document? Where did you get `_highlightDoc` from? I don't see that anywhere in @Noitidart's code.

Regading yoru comment on iterate all words and use gFindBar._highlightDoc:

> I did it with 'gFindBar._highlightDoc(true, word)' now. I'm using firefox 17, so i dont know if gFindBar is state of the art. –  jervis 39 mins ago

Dude why do that.... I saw @Noitidart posted a per word solution on the linked topic: `gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[0].linkedBrowser.finder.highlight(true, 'YOUR_WORD_HERE');` that is extremely easy, one line and no need to create text nodes spans or anything. You have to run this code on each tab you want to highlight in.

Comment: Well, i have a list with blacklisted words which i don't want to highlight. So using the finder (which i couldn't find in the DOM structure and using it gave me type errors) is just a workaround, because when 'apple' is blacklisted, and the word 'a' appears in the documents content, 'apple' gets partially highlighted. The build-in function of firefox for highlighting isn't compatible with my tought of tokenizing, i think.

Comment: Dude how much can one do for you? Do some work look at the code, it can iterate through all ranges. So do find 'a' for example and then iterate through just those returned ranges, and if a is surrounded by two non-word characters then highlight it else dont.